# How do I provide inline input to an IPython (notebook) shell command?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I want to put together an IPython notebook with some shell commands and their input. In the bash prompt I can use "here-document" syntax:

```bash
bash-3.2$ mysql -u root <<END_IPUT
> use mydb;
> show tables;
> END_INPUT
```

How do I get the same effect in IPython, and specifically in a jupyter notebook? I know how to execute shell commands as IPython as "line magics" or "cell
 magics", e.g.:

```python
In [7]:  !! ls -tF
Out[7]:  ['Demo-notebook.ipynb',
          'createdb.sql',
          ...
```

I've looked at [IPython as a system shell](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/shell.html), which shows how to enable some syntactic niceties. After the following, I can run system commands without prepending `!` or `!!`

```python
# Turn everything in $PATH into an alias; 
# then enable calling aliases without ! or %
%rehashx      
%autocall 2
```

But none of this helps with providing input to these commands inline: The here-document syntax is invalid in IPython, and results in a python `SyntaxError`. So how do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried the bash cell magic? Start a cell with the line `%%bash`, and put bash code in the rest of it.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks! I'd already found `%%sx`, which does the same I think. But the documentation for `%bash` led me to `%%script`, which is _exactly_ what I was looking for. In the meantime I also found an extension specifically for `sql`, which solved my immediate problem even better. But if you want to write an answer expanding on your suggestion, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Thomas, before you delete my tag for a third time, look at how many people follow each one. If  [tag:ipython-notebook] is such a problem, please take up the process to have the tags merged.

Comment: I am trying to merge the tags, but I can't do that until the new tag has 80% as many uses as the old. I am periodically sweeping new questions over to the new tag to boost its numbers. Thanks.

Comment: I see. Well, please stop deleting my tags. Having both should be good enough for you. (And just **add** [tag:jupyter-notebook] to other questions.) And making the tags themselves synonyms, of course.

Comment: I made jupyter-notebook a synonym for ipython-notebook, but you'll have to do it the other way around. (I don't have enough privileges in the new tag.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bash cell magic allows you to enter multiple lines of bash. Just start any cell with `%%bash`:

```
%%bash
echo "This is bash"
ls
```

If you're using a heredoc to pipe text into another program, you can also use the script cell magic:

```
%%script bc
2+3
```

There may also be other cell magics which address your problem more specifically!

Comment: there is few small differences between `!` and `%%bash` when running a command. 1. `%%bash` doesn't display ASCII colors, while color appear fine using`!`. 2. `%%bash` collect the output and flush them on the screen once while `!` displays the output one by one as it executes.

Answer (score 6):

With some more research, and with the help of @ThomasK's tip (see accepted answer), I found a couple of ways to do this.

- One solution is the cell magic `%sx`. It executes the cell contents as a bash script, and captures and returns the output as a list of lines. Sometimes handy, sometimes not.

  ```sh
  In[1]:  %%sx
          echo Hello, world
          cat -n <<DATA
          this
          and that
          DATA

  Out[1]: ['Hello, world', '     1\tthis', '     2\tand that']
  ```
- Change that to `%%bash`, as `@ThomasK` suggested, and the output is printed out, not returned. To capture it for further processing, `ipython` provides the `--out` parameter. But then I need to print it myself-- it won't show up by default.

  ```sh
  In[1]:  %%bash --out var
          echo Hello, world
          echo "   Again"

  In[2]:  var

  Out[2]: 'Hello, world\n   Again\n'
  ```
- `%%bash` is actually shorthand for `%%script bash`, billed as working "like the `#!` line in a script" (see the help with `%%script?`). Which it does. So here's how to dispense with the here-document syntax and have any program read the cell contents as input. `%%script` also accepts the `--out` parameter.

  ```sh
          %%script --out var mysql -u root -p XYZ
          USE somedb;
          SELECT * FROM users
               WHERE passwd IS NULL\G
  ```

This is nice enough, but I ended up not using it because my use case is `mysql`, and eventually I discovered that there's a great third-party [`ipython-sql`](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql/blob/master/README.rst) extension that I can use instead:

```sh
%load_ext sql
%sql mysql+pymysql://user:passwd@localhost/somedb
```

This presupposes installing the extension, with `pip install ipython-sql`. For `mysql`, I also needed `pip install pymysql`. After the above setup, I just talk to the database like this

```sh
In[1]:  %%sql 
        SELECT * FROM users
            WHERE passwd IS NULL

Out[1]: 1 rows affected.
        ...
```

The returned table is actually *drawn* as a notebook table with borders, which is kinda nice. And it is made available as a Pandas dataframe (a smart list), which I can grab from `_`.

Comment: Could I do: `%%bash /usr/bin/env ipython` in order to run an exported `notebook.py` at the command line?