# Convert ipython notebook to directly-executable python script

Tags: python, bash, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a `jupyter/ipython` notebook that I am using for prototyping and tutoring.

I export it as a python script using the menu dropdown or `nbconvert`, i.e.

```
ipython nbconvert --to python notebook.ipynb
```

However, I would like to make `notebook.py` executable directly without having to hack it by hand each time, in order that I can keep updating `notebook.ipynb` and overwriting `notebook.py` with my changes. I also want to include command-line arguments in `notebook.py`. My boilerplate is, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
import sys
x=sys.argv[-1]
```

with `chmod +x notebook.py` of course.

One route could be to make these lines (be they python or command-line directives) ignorable in the `jupyter/ipython` notebook - is there a way to do this by e.g. detecting the `jupyter/ipython` environment?

**Edit1:** This is tantamount to saying:

How can I include lines in the `notebook.ipynb` that will be ignored in the notebook environment but parsed in `notebook.py` generated from it?

**Edit2:** This question is a partial answer, but doesn't tell me how to include the `#!/usr/bin/env ipython` line: [How can I check if code is executed in the IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411967/how-can-i-check-if-code-is-executed-in-the-ipython-notebook)

**Edit3:** Could be useful, but only if `%%bash /usr/bin/env ipython` would work - would it..? [How do I provide inline input to an IPython (notebook) shell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253817/how-do-i-provide-inline-input-to-an-ipython-notebook-shell-command)

**Edit4:** Another attempted answer (subtle): Since `#` is a comment in python, putting `#!/usr/bin/env ipython` in the first cell of the notebook means that it will be ignored in `jupyter/ipython`, but respected in the exported `notebook.py`. However, the `#!` directive is not at the top, but can easily be chopped off:

```
> more notebook.py 

# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:

#!/usr/bin/env ipython


# In[2]:

print 'Hello'


# In[ ]:
```

Comment: When you say directly, what method or portal are you referring to? Do you mean from the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: On the *nix command line, i.e. `./notebook.py` - I know how to do this, but I want to (i) export the notebook and (ii) make it executable without having to hack it by hand every time, also allowing for command-line arguments via e.g. `sys.argv`

Comment: I have edited the question - does the edit make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turned out to be rather straightforward.

**Part 1 - Making the exported notebook.py directly executable:**

As described [here](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html), `nbconvert` can be customized with arbitrary templates.

So create a file `hashbang.tpl` containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
{% extends 'python.tpl'%}
```

Then at the command line execute:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python 'notebook.ipynb' --stdout --template=hashbang.tpl > notebook.py
```

Hey presto:

```
> more notebook.py

#!/usr/bin/env ipython

# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:

print 'Hello'
...
```

**Part 2 - Detecting the notebook environment:**

This answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662359/1021819 should do it, i.e. use the following function to test for the notebook environment:

```
def isnotebook():
    # From https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662359/1021819
    try:
        shell = get_ipython().__class__.__name__
        if shell == 'ZMQInteractiveShell':
            return True   # Jupyter notebook or qtconsole
        elif shell == 'TerminalInteractiveShell':
            return False  # Terminal running IPython
        else:
            return False  # Other type (?)
    except NameError:
        return False      # Probably standard Python interpreter
```